# Cannot compile diagnostic_updater on ARM device: "apt: command [sudo apt-get install python-rospkg] failed"

Tags: robotic-arm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to compile diagnostic_updater on a ARM device (running Linaro 12.08) using groovy. The command I'm using to compile is

```
rosdep install diagnostic_updater
```

The error I'm encountering is

```
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
apt: command [sudo apt-get install python-rospkg] failed
```

The reason the command is failing is because python-rospkg doesn't exist as a debian package for ROS. I had acquired rospkg through pip.

Is there are work around I can use to build the package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51726/cannot-compile-diagnostic_updater-on-arm-device:-%22apt:-command-%5Bsudo-apt-get-install-python-rospkg%5D-failed%22/) by [derekjchow](https://answers.ros.org/users/2190/derekjchow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 341 on 2013-01-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosdep install attempts to install system dependencies via apt.

If that fails on Debian, you need to install system dependencies another way.

If rospkg is the only dependency rosdep misses for diagnostic_updater, and you have installed it via pip, then you should be good to go (perform the next build step).

So rosdep is just blind for your pip installation of rospkg.

Remember to get the latest of rospkg from pip, though.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2